# RegEx help for IIS URL Rewrite

Tags: regex, iis, url, url-rewriting

I need to take request for

```
www.domain.com/123456/Catalog.aspx
```

and rewrite to

```
www.domain.com/Products/Catalog.aspx?ItemID=123456
```

where `123456` will always be numbers.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you just trying to capture the 6 numbers between the forward slashes? If so this says look ahead for text that matches www.domain.com/ and then 6 digits and if found then return a match that captures the 6 digits into a capture group called itemId and the everything after that into a capture group called page. (?=www.domain.com/\d{6})^www.domain.com/(?P<itemId>\d{6})/(?P<page>.*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to match this pattern:

```
^(\d+)/([^/]+)$
```

And then rewrite to this URL:

```
Products/{R:2}?ItemId={R:1}
```